# How do I calculate an average from averages in a dictionary with multiple values in each key without using sum()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Credits to someone who helped me in a previous post, I am able to find the averages of each class in the dictionary and print out the average of the averages with this code:

```
def avg(classes):
    average = {}
    for classnames, grades in classes.items():
        average[classnames] = sum(grades) / len(grades)
    return average

classes = {"Spanish II": [100, 99, 100, 98], "US History I": [95, 96, 97, 94]}
averages = avg(classes)
print("Average grades in each class:", averages)

average_of_averages = sum(averages.values())/len(averages)
print("Average of average grades:", average_of_averages)
```

I just want to know if there is a way to calculate the averages (for both the average grade in each class and the average of those averages totaled together) without using the built-in function sum().

I'm thinking I need a nested for loop: one loop for an average in each class and then another loop to find the average of these averages, but I don't know how to do this because there's multiple values in each key.

Comment: Think in terms of functions. You can't use `sum` for some reason. Well- write a function to do what you need it to. What would `def custom_sum(list_of_ints):` look like?

Comment: @j1-lee I am just testing out different ways to practice Python dictionaries, I know using sum() is the most simple way but I think it just helps me more to practice using different ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply add a second loop as follows:

```
def avg(classes):
    average = {}
    for classnames in classes:
        total = 0
        for grade in classes[classnames]:
            total += grade        
        average[classnames] = total / len(classes[classnames])
    return average

classes = {"Spanish II": [100, 99, 100, 98], "US History I": [95, 96, 97, 94]}
averages = avg(classes)
print("Average grades in each class:", averages)

total_averages = 0
for classname in averages:
    total_averages += averages[classname]
average_of_averages = total_averages / len(averages)

print("Average of average grades:", average_of_averages)
```

If you would like, you can also completely skip the part of calculating each of the individual class averages, and just calculate the entire average at once as follows:

```
def avg(classes):
    total = 0
    total_length = 0
    for classnames in classes:
        for grade in classes[classnames]:
            total += grade        
        total_length += len(classes[classnames])
    return total / total_length

classes = {"Spanish II": [100, 99, 100, 98], "US History I": [95, 96, 97, 94]}
average_of_averages = avg(classes)
print("Average of average grades:", average_of_averages)
```

Comment: To get average_of_averages, is there another way I can do it without using sum() in the line?

Comment: @shook Yes! You can use a similar loop to calculate that aswell, I have edited my answer to show this

Answer (score 3):

why not use `pandas` instead it is much simpler and faster than using loops. Here's the code you will need to use:

```
import pandas as pd

classes = {"Spanish II": [100, 99, 100, 98], "US History I": [95, 96, 97, 94]}

df = pd.DataFrame(classes)

avg = df.mean()

avg_of_avg = avg.mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `numpy.mean()` and cast `averages.values()` to list

```
import numpy as np
def avg(classes):
    average = {}
    for classnames, grades in classes.items():
        average[classnames] = np.mean(grades)
    return average

classes = {"Spanish II": [100, 99, 100, 98], "US History I": [95, 96, 97, 94]}

averages = avg(classes)
print("Average grades in each class:", averages)

average_of_averages = np.mean(list(averages.values()))
print("Average of average grades:", average_of_averages)
```